# TouchNGo opener failure to open

Tags: garage-door-opener

When opening my garage door from my car, I note that, only recently, the door opens and then closes a few inches, and then opens a few inches, and so on. How do I fix this?

Comment: You have to provide a more coherent explanation of what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

Probably by unhooking the opener, operating the door manually, noting were the problems are, and adjusting or lubricating or replacing bad rollers to restore smooth operation by hand, leading to smooth operation by opener.

If there are no problems, sticky spots, difficult areas of movement when operating by hand, the opener itself becomes suspect. Aside from checking it for needs in the lubrication and adjustment realm, that quickly bifurcates into

1. "replace the whole opener" (advantage - guaranteed item)

   or
2. "start replacing parts" advantage - CAN be cheaper if the parts fix
   the problem. Disadvantage - parts are often not returnable and may
   not fix the problem, depending what the problem is, so there's a
   potential for it to cost more if you end up needing to replace the
   whole thing anyway.